# Java StringReader ready()

Tags: java, stringreader

Hi this is my first question here so if it is for some reason does not obey the rules, turns out to be a duplicate or whatever, please tell me kindly (not that I have any reputation to lose in the first place)

Anyway, I actually have sort of 2 questions about this class StringReader that Java provides. First, what exactly the StringReader.ready() do? Can I use it as a condition in a while loop so that the loop terminates when the string ends? Reading the java doc didn't help much (or maybe I misunderstood what they meant by "Returns True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input")

#### Update:

Sorry apparently I missed the part where it says `read()` returns -1 when the string ends. Anyway, my question remains for the ready() part. I thought this is supposed to be the one that checks if the string has ended?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

[Link to the actual source code](https://github.com/digawp/textgenerator)

The snippet that causes the problem:

```
while (text.ready()) {

        // Updating stringBuffer, using some sort of 'rolling hash' (or is
        // it
        // indeed rolling hash?)
        stringBuffer.deleteCharAt(0);
        stringBuffer.append((char) next);

        // The next character that follows the sequence of k characters
        next = text.read();

        // store the string form of the buffer to avoid rebuilding the
        // string for the next few checks
        String key = stringBuffer.toString();

        if (hashmap.containsKey(key)) {
            // If the hash map already contain the key, retrieve the array
            asciiArray = hashmap.get(key);
        } else {
            // Else, create a new one
            asciiArray = new int[128];
        }
        System.out.println(next);

        // Error checking on my side only, because some of the text sample I
        // used contains some characters that is outside the 128 ASCII
        // character, for whatever reason
        if (next > 127) {
            continue;
        }

        // Increment the appropriate character in the array
        asciiArray[next]++;
        // Put into the hash map
        hashmap.put(key, asciiArray);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First, what exactly the StringReader.ready() do?

The general contract is that returns true if the next read won't block. In the case of `StringReader` that is always true.

> Can I use it as a condition in a while loop so that the loop terminates when the string ends? Reading the java doc didn't help much (or maybe I misunderstood what they meant by "Returns True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input")

No. A simple test reveals that. You should loop until `read()` returns -1. Note that you must store the result of `read()` into an `int` for this to work.

> In the while loop that I have constructed, the method StringReader.read() somehow returns -1.

No 'somehow' about it. That's what it's supposed to do.

> What does this mean?

It means end of stream. In this case, you've read all the characters out of the `StringReader.`

> Again, the Java doc did not help.

On the contrary. The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html#read%28%29) clearly states that `read()` returns "the character read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached".

> I am guessing that it means that the string has already terminated

No need to guess about it. That's explicitly what the Javadoc says.

> but then that means the ready() method is not doing what it is supposed to do!

No it doesn't. The Javadoc doesn't say that `ready()` returns `false` at end of stream. You don't have any warrant for that statement. In this case, it returned true, you called `read()`, and it didn't block. Contract satisfied.

Comment: Wow a very detailed answer. Thanks and sorry about the read() returns -1 part. I missed that when I scheme through the doc

Answer (score 0):

To help you better understand the concept, let's say your `StringReader` is reading a sequences of characters from a *slooooow* TCP connection, at a rate of one character per-second...

If you then call `StringReader.read()` in a while loop, then each time `read()` will wait for 1 second before returning a character. This can be a problem if you don't want your code to hang there waiting for characters to come in. That's when `StringReader.ready()` becomes handy. If it returns false, then that means a call to `read()` may cause the code to block (waiting), whereas if `ready()` returns true it means a call to `read()` will *immediately* returns a value (character or -1) without blocking/waiting.

Now let's say all the characters have already been transferred through the connection, and the connection is therefore closed, then `ready()` will still return true because it knows it doesn't need to wait for the next character (since there is none). Now when you call `read()`, it will also *immediately* returns, but this time with a -1, meaning no more characters.

Now let's get back to your code. For what you are trying to achieve, you don't need to use `ready()`. Instead, the first line of your code should be changed to:

```
int ch;

while (true)
{
    ch = text.read();
    if (ch < 0) break;

    ...
```

Comment: (1) Returning false doesn't mean a call to `.read()` will block. The [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#ready()) explicitly says the opposite. (2) Returning true doesn't mean that `read()` will immediately return a character. That's what the question is about. It might return -1 meaning end of stream.

Comment: There, I've changed 'will' to 'may', and 'character' to 'value'. Happy? In all practical purpose, you can actually assume it's 'will'. The reason that Javadoc says that returning false does not mean the next call to `read()` will block is because _by the time_ you call `read()`, a character may have been available and hence ready.

Comment: I see.. I guess I get BufferedReader and StringReader mixed up (or rather, I assume that they are similar). Thank you for your answer! Sorry can't vote up your answer as I dont have enough reputation point haha

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code of `StringReader.ready()` method you can find the answer. `StringReader` is a decorator class written to read `String`s using a reader. You can only create a `StringReader` instance by passing a String argument in.

The `StringReader.ready()` will always return true and only throw an `IOException` if the `String` passed while instantiating is null

```
 public boolean ready() throws IOException {
     synchronized (lock) {
        ensureOpen();
        return true;
     }
 }

 /** Check to make sure that the stream has not been closed */
 private void ensureOpen() throws IOException {
     if (str == null)
        throw new IOException("Stream closed");
 }
```